# How can we ensure delivery in key-based routing?

Tags: routes, distributed, distributed-system

I've read that distributed hash tables such as Kademlia and Chord use key-based routing (using a xor based distance metric on hashes in a routing table). I'd like to implement this key-based routing protocol in one of my programs without implementing a full distributed hash table.

My program requires guaranteed delivery though, and I've read that sometimes key-based routing gets close to the desired destination, but never quite reaches it.

Is there any way to guarantee delivery in a key-based routing sceme?